# Android adjustPan is being ignored

Tags: android

ca) I have an activity in an EditText in it. If I show this activity directly, adjustPan works fine when soft keyboard is shown.

b) If I show the same activity under TabActivity as one of the tabs, adjustPan is not working (not doing anything).

c) I converted the activity to a fragment and tried the same thing with Fragments API but adjust pan is not working that way as well.

I already set windowSoftInputMode to adjustPan on TabActivity and other activity in question in case (b), and on FragmentActivity in case (c).

I also have full screen theme, I tried removing it as well but it didn't change anything.

Anything else I need to do to make this work in one of these other situations?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I had WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS flag set somewhere and when I removed it, it started to work in all cases.

Comment: Can you please clarify where you had set that flag and on which view? I'm currently facing the exact same issue and going crazy over trying to fix it.