# Edittext multiline in Constraints Layout and adjustpan scrollview not workable

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I use `EditText` in a `fragment` which is in a `constraintsLayout`, but the `editText` do not move up when I typed more line which is more than the screen length.

I tried setting "`windowSoftInputMode`" to "`adjustPan`" and "`adjustResize`", tried setting "`isScrollContainer`" true and false.

I tried using a `scrollview` and set my `EditText` as its child. But all having same problem.

My activity is not fullscreen.

The code below is my `manifest`

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="userPortrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan">
```

and the following codes are my layout, it is in a constraints layout.

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine|textWebEditText"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:saveEnabled="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:hint="@string/writeYourPostHere"/>
```

This is the appearance of my fragment before typing anything.
[image: appearance of my fragment before typing anything]

This is the appearance of my fragment when I typed 20 lines of words "testing" with "line number",it did not move up and the remaining words (Testing 18, Testing 19, Testing 20) are hidden even though I am still typing the words "Testing 20". I want it to move up and show the last words I had typed.

[image]

I already read the answer in the following link, but they all appeared the same and cannot solve my problem.

[EditText, adjustPan, ScrollView issue in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449152/edittext-adjustpan-scrollview-issue-in-android)

[adjustPan not preventing keyboard from covering EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558810/adjustpan-not-preventing-keyboard-from-covering-edittext)

[Forcing adjustPan in activity containing ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114993/forcing-adjustpan-in-activity-containing-scrollview)

[Android EditText Multiline with SoftInputMode adjustPan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774512/android-edittext-multiline-with-softinputmode-adjustpan)

[How to avoid soft keyboard pushing up my layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516216/how-to-avoid-soft-keyboard-pushing-up-my-layout/12956520#12956520)

[Soft keyboard hides parts of fullscreen webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155577/soft-keyboard-hides-parts-of-fullscreen-webview/28155820#28155820)

[Android adjustPan is being ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101825/android-adjustpan-is-being-ignored)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by using following method.

1)put the `scrollview` outside the `constraintslayout`, previously I just use the `scrollview` with `edittext` as the only child.

```
<ScrollView>
    <ConstraintsLayout>
        <EditText>
        </>
    </>
</>
```

2) For the `editText`, the setting is

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```

3) Lastly, i put this code at the `onCreateView` for the `fragment`.

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Comment: Indeed you can just use


getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);



to achieve panning on your edittext. You can leave constraint out of the scrollview.